# Is there any chance of ClassCastException/IllegalStateException with this java code?

Tags: java, exception, casting, classcastexception, illegalstateexception

I was a bit confused with both classcastexception and illegalstateexception, as it seems similar in most of the cases.

Here i come across with an issue in this java code

```
 class consumer
    {
         LOC----
    }

     public class provider extends consumer
       {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            consumer st=new provider();     
            provider est=(provider)st;
        }
     }
```

I was stuck with this part. According to me, it should generate an exception (classcast or illegalstate). but there is no exception in execution, there might be a classcastexception or an illegalstateexception. But the code executes without any exception, Reason???

I was a bit week in exception handling, trying hard to master exception handling. can any one explain why it doesn't show error at the lines

```
    consumer st=new provider();     
    provider est=(provider)st;
```

Also explain classcast and illegalstate exceptions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you expect a ClassCastException here?
`st` is a `provider`, you explicitely created one, so assigning a `provider` object to a reference of type `provider` is OK.

The only thing is that the compiler does not 'know' that `st` will point to a `provider` object at runtime. Because the static type of `st` is `consumer`, the explicit cast to `provider` is required in the second line. But that's nothing special...

Comment: @gimibarak - st is a "reference" to a consumer "object"... understand the difference..

Comment: yaa, st is a ref to consumer pointing to provider obj. sorry got it.. and thanks @X86

Answer (score 1):

consumer st=new provider();

Here you are pointing to a provider object (RHS) and telling - "This is a consumer"(reference) , Which is true because provider extends consumer.

```
  provider est=(provider)st;
```

Here, you are pointing to a provider object (RHS) and telling- "This is a provider"(reference). Which is also correct. So, you should/will not get any error.

Answer (score 0):

The `ClassCastException` is thrown by the JVM when you try to cast an object to a type which is unreachable in this hierarchy.

As per your code, there is no reason for such exception and here there is why:

1) You have two classes: `consumer` and `provider`, and the latter extends the former:

```
public class provider extends consumer
```

2) Your code is instantiating a `provider` class and assigning it to a `consumer` variable:

```
consumer st=new provider();
```

There is no reason here for any kind of exception, since `provider` extends `consumer`, all instances of a `provider` class are also a `consumer`, so you can use the `consumer` type to reference any kind of `provider`.

3) You are casting a `provider` instance into a ... (drum roll) `provider` instance!:

```
provider est=(provider)st;
```

The variable `st` is of `consumer` type, true; but you initialised it as `provider` before (remember the `new provider()` statement). So, internally it's a `provider` not a `consumer` so when make that cast nothing wrong happens.

`IllegalStateExceptions` work in a different way, some classes from the JVM can throw it due to a number of reasons. Even your code can throw it attending to your specific needs. The reason why is it thrown depends on each class implementation.

Answer (score 0):

A `ClassCastException` is thrown when objects of incompatible types are casted. For instance

```
consumer c = new consumer();
provider p = (provider) c;
```

the above code will throw a classCastException as an object of type consumer can never be anprovider object.

In your code you are  creating an object of type `provider` and assigning that to a reference of type `consumer`. This is perfectly legal because all methods that would be in a `consumer` object will be in `provider` object. so there won't be any exception thrown. It is called an **Upcast**.

When you are downcasting that is casting a an object from parent class to child class there may be a ClassCastException thrown if the object being cast is of the parent class type and the reference is of the child class type.

```
provider p = (provider) c; // will give you a ClassCastException
```

as the methods in the class `Child` will not be present in the parent class which will cause a meltdown at runtime if a child specific method is called on a Parent type Object.

Answer (score 0):

nothing wrong with program ..so it will run without any exception...
But if you will try without excception then it will give error at compile time...
try this program for class cast exeption

```
class consumer
{
int a=0;
void method(Object ob)
{
    consumer st=(consumer)ob;
}

}
public class provider
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    consumer st=new consumer();     
    provider est=new provider();
    st.method(est);
}
}
```